# PDFDocument removePageAtIndex for 10.8.4 Exception Raised

Tags: cocoa, exception, pdf, quartz-graphics

I got a strange bug using PDFDocument with Mountain Lion 10.8.4, I cannot use the method removePageAtIndex. It will always crash.

The code is quite straight forward

```
    PDFDocument* theOldPDF = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL:[panel URL]];
    [theOldPDF pageCount];
    NSLog(@"[theOldPDF pageCount] : %lu",[theOldPDF pageCount]);
    [theOldPDF removePageAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"PAGE REMOVED");
```

And here are the exception raised when the document is open:

```
2013-06-08 22:05:59.120 test pdf remove crash[3978:303] [theOldPDF pageCount] : 10
2013-06-08 22:05:59.124 test pdf remove crash[3978:303] -[__NSCFNumber annotations]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x187
2013-06-08 22:05:59.128 test pdf remove crash[3978:303] An uncaught exception was raised
2013-06-08 22:05:59.128 test pdf remove crash[3978:303] -[__NSCFNumber annotations]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x187
2013-06-08 22:05:59.132 test pdf remove crash[3978:303] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff99048b06 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff920c23f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff990df40a -[NSObject(NSObject) does    NotRecognizeSelector:] + 186
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9903702e ___forwarding___ + 414
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff99036e18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
    5   PDFKit                              0x00007fff936e1fde -[PDFDocument removePageAtIndex:] + 408
    6   test pdf remove crash               0x00000001000013fc -[AppDelegate openDocument:] + 476
```

As the log shows, the PDF have 10 pages, I try to remove the first one, (or any of them for that matter), and it will crash.

Does somebody already got this kind of issue? This happen only with 10.8.4, was working fine so far.

Thanks

Comment: You should submit this, including your test project, to Apple's bug reporter: https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: Thanks Peter. I will submit it to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

There is a temporary but functional workaround proposed here:
http://openradar.appspot.com/14081212

Comment: thanks for the link. In the mean time I created my own removePageAtIndex method, but your workaround is nicer.